# How do I keep one figure in its place and move the rest to the end?

Tags: floats, positioning, endfloat

I am working on my thesis with many chapters. In one of it, I use a lot of figure and table.  I have been able to use `endfloat` to send all of the figure and table. However, other chapter has only one figure and I want to keep it in the original position.

Is it possible to bypass `endfloat` to several chapter? Or should I use float and then use option p in the chapter in which I want to send all figure and table to the end of chapter?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: if it is possible to avoid using a float for the single figure that you want to stay in place, you can place it directly in line, and use `\captionof` (from the `caption` package) to label it.  of course, you'll have to manage the positioning and spacing manually.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `endfloat` dose not provide an option to keep your figure unmoved. So a tricky way is to define another `figure` environment. But then they are using different counters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{newfloat}
    \DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lof,name=Light Figure,placement=h!]{lightfigure}
\begin{document}
    Lorem
    \begin{figure}
        \rule{2cm}{2cm}
        \caption{big box}
    \end{figure}
    ipsum
    \begin{lightfigure}
        \rule{1cm}{1cm}
        \caption{small box}
    \end{lightfigure}
    dolor
\end{document}
```